# Adding a button to footer that shows a list with options

Tags: react-native, footer

I created a footer for my app which let's the user browse to different pages. However, there are too many screens to display so I wanted to create one button on the right which let's the user see a list with additional screens that can be opened. I found this to be quite common in other apps, see below an example where the 'more'-button would give that functionality (i.e., open list of other screens that user can choose):

How it should look like

[image: 1]

I googled but could not find example code with this functionality. I read about 'Modals' but was not sure if this works in a footer and/or is the most simple solution.

This is the items in my footer that I would like to edit to show a list with additional screens instead of just linking to one screen:

```
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.innerBox} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("TabsScreenD")}>
      <Entypo name="dots-three-horizontal" size={40} color="white" />
      <Text style={[Styles.text14L,{color:color.white, textAlign:"center"}]} >
            More
            </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Since I am very new to react-native I am looking for a simple solution.

Many thanks!

EDIT:
Unfortunately, I am not able to implement the solution proposed below. It seems not to fit with the current structure of my app or I am not editing the right parts of the code.

Here are additional details of what my app currently looks like:

App.js:

```
const App = props => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppNavigator />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

AppNavigator.js:

```
export const AppNavigator = props => {
  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
     <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
        initialRouteName={"SplashScreen"}
        >
       <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={SplashScreen} />
       <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
       <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
       </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

FooterTabs.js:

```
const FooterTabs = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.innerBox} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("HomeScreen")}>
            <AntDesign name="home" size={40} color="white" />
            <Text style={[Styles.text14L,{color:color.white, textAlign:"center"}]}>
            Home
            </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
               
      <View style={styles.line} />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.innerBox} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("TabsScreenD")}>
      <Entypo name="dots-three-horizontal" size={40} color="white" />
      <Text style={[Styles.text14L,{color:color.white, textAlign:"center"}]} >
            More
            </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Sorry, this is kinda lengthy. I tried to shorten where possible. Can anyone give me advice on what I need to edit. Based on Nazir's answer below I tried to replace 'FooterTabs' with a TabNavigator, but could not integrate it properly.

Thanks again!

Comment: I edited the above to show more details of the code I am using. So far, I was still not able to solve the problem, any help would be very welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should use [Tab Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/) for your footer and [Stack Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/) for your screens.

```
   import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import StackNavigator from './StackNavigator'

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Entries" component={HomeScreen} />
<Tab.Screen name="State" component={HomeScreen} />
<Tab.Screen name="Plus" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Calender" component={SettingsScreen} />
<Tab.Screen name="More" component={StackNavigator} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

and in `StackNavigator.js` file you have to create Stack Navigator which will have multiple screens as you want.

```
   import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function StackNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
export default StackNavigator;
```

if you want to hide Tabs when inner screen of more tab is visible you will have to change the structure of navigation.

```
<Stack.Navigator {...props}>
<Stack.Screen component={()=>
 <Tab.Navigator>
<Tab.screen />
<Tab.screen />
<Tab.screen />
<Tab.screen />
</Tab.Navigator>
}/>

<Stack.Screen name='ScreenName1' component={Component1}/>
<Stack.Screen name='ScreenName2' component={Component2}/>
<Stack.Screen name='ScreenName3' component={Component3}/>
.....
....
...
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: HI Nazir, thanks for your reply! I am not sure if I am completely following your answer. I already have a stack navigator which contains all screens of the app. So would I need to create a second one with only the screens that should be in the 'More'-menu? I also have a file FooterTabs.js which creates the footer. However, that one does not use a TabNavigator ("const FooterTabs = ({navigation}) => {code with buttons and links to different screens)"). Do I need to replace that entirely with the TabNavigator that you posted above? Again, many thanks for your help!

Comment: yes I will be easy to maintain if you use tabnavigaion instead of custom tab logic.
and if you have stack navigator with having all screens then you dont need to create another stack for more tab

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Another question: Since my stacknavigator contains all screens in the app, how do I select the screens to show for the 'More'-button? Is that the last snippet you posted?

Comment: yes the use this last snippet structure

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to integrate the proposed solution into my code. I added additional details of my code in the original post. Maybe you could give me an example on how / what to edit exactly?

Answer (score 0):

To demo this, I have added the code below, also the tutorial I personally follow which helped me clear many crucial concepts like this is also mentioned below.
I have just displayed a full-screen view in the demo, but you can customize it accordingly since you want a list of screens to go into.
When the `+` tab is pressed, I am presenting a view with a red background color.

Free course (Step by step guide on how to show a modal on tab press) - [Here](https://learn.reactnativeschool.com/courses/enrolled/804752)

Code - [Here](https://github.com/bhishaksanyal/tabbar-modal-react-navigation)

Recording - [Here](https://www.veed.io/view/8026a446-23e2-4ce6-86b2-00b69c7fdc00?sharingWidget=true&panel=share)

Kindly have a look and comment if you have further questions.